# How to show which user is login on into my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Java servlet where i am validating which user is login i am storing that values into variables what i want to achieve is that to show on my welcome page that this user is loged his name and company name
here is my Json

```
[{"Name":"admin","Companyname":"ABC PVT LTD"}]
```

this my navebar

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark navbar fixed-top">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul id="navbarId" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

    </ul>

  </div>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="Header.html">HOME</a>

</nav>
<div style="padding: 30px"></div>



<div class="col-sm-12">
  //here i want to show like Welcome 'admin' - 'ABC PVT LTD'
  <hr style="border: solid 1px black">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like `$(".name").text("Welcome '" +obj[0].Name + "'-" +obj[0].Companyname)`

```
var obj = [{"Name":"admin","Companyname":"ABC PVT LTD"}];

$(".name").text("Welcome '" +obj[0].Name + "'-" +obj[0].Companyname)
```

**Working demo**

```js
var obj = [{"Name":"admin","Companyname":"ABC PVT LTD"}];

$(".name").text("Welcome '" +obj[0].Name + "'-" +obj[0].Companyname)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav
        class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark navbar fixed-top">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul id="navbarId" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

            </ul>

        </div>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="Header.html">HOME</a>

    </nav>
    <div style="padding: 30px"></div>



    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="name"></div>
        <hr style="border: solid 1px black">  
    </div>
```

Comment: @viveksingh try look now